# Python stuck on dictionary writing to file in order

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have question about this problem below; my output should look like this below.

Output:

```
ID    Exam1    Exam2    Homework    Attendance    Project1    Project2    Class Recap    Final Grade    Potential Grade
32165487    10    70    50    40    100    80    50    100    D
21321853    52    95    72    56    95    32    56    100    C+
41861235    95    12    47    32    68    92    35    100    D
84534853    58    38    84    84    89    68    74    100    C
```

Code:

```
def generateReport(gradebook):
    outfile=open('gradebook.txt','w')
    currentstud=[]

    for stu in d:
        #print(stu)
        currentstud.append(d[stu])
        whatever={}
        lst1=[]
    for students in currentstud:
        print(students)
        grades1=[]
    for grades in students:  
        outfile.write(grades + '\t')
    outfile.write('\n')
    for val in students.values():

        outfile.write(val + '\t') 
    outfile.close



    d={'37340752': {'exam1': '50', 'project1': '40', 'classrecap': '39', 'homework': '62', 'exam2': '3', 'attendance': '17', 'project2': '86', 'id': '37340752'},
       '95255664': {'exam1': '76', 'project1': '60', 'classrecap': '39', 'homework': '81', 'exam2': '57', 'attendance': '19', 'project2': '42', 'id': '95255664'},
       '47718233': {'exam1': '81', 'project1': '55', 'classrecap': '53', 'homework': '46', 'exam2': '46', 'attendance': '4', 'project2': '14', 'id': '47718233'},
       '55527760': {'exam1': '34', 'project1': '89', 'classrecap': '39', 'homework': '19', 'exam2': '99', 'attendance': '78', 'pta': 65, 'project2': '99', 'id': '55527760'},
       '32548926': {'exam1': '9', 'project1': '7', 'classrecap': '77', 'homework': '98', 'exam2': '1', 'attendance': '43', 'project2': '86', 'id': '32548926'}}

    print(generateReport(d))
```

This is the output I get for above code. How do I make it print all of lines instead of just one?

```
project1    homework    attendance  id  exam2   exam1   project2    classrecap  
55  46  4   47718233    46  81  14  53
```

Comment: Your post and code formatting is off: please correct so that it is readable.

Comment: On a side note, `outfile.close` does not close the file.  You would need parentheses: `outfile.close()`, or (better) use a `with` block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Put grade for all student (grade loop should be inside student)**

```
def generateReport(gradebook):
    outfile=open('gradebook.txt','w')
    currentstud=[]
    for stu in d:
        currentstud.append(d[stu])
    for grades in currentstud[0]:
        outfile.write(grades + '\t')
    outfile.write('\n') 
    for students in currentstud:
        for val in students.values():
            outfile.write(str(val) + '\t')
        outfile.write('\n')
    outfile.close



d={'37340752': {'exam1': '50', 'project1': '40', 'classrecap': '39', 'homework': '62', 'exam2': '3', 'attendance': '17', 'project2': '86', 'id': '37340752'},
       '95255664': {'exam1': '76', 'project1': '60', 'classrecap': '39', 'homework': '81', 'exam2': '57', 'attendance': '19', 'project2': '42', 'id': '95255664'},
       '47718233': {'exam1': '81', 'project1': '55', 'classrecap': '53', 'homework': '46', 'exam2': '46', 'attendance': '4', 'project2': '14', 'id': '47718233'},
       '55527760': {'exam1': '34', 'project1': '89', 'classrecap': '39', 'homework': '19', 'exam2': '99', 'attendance': '78', 'pta': 65, 'project2': '99', 'id': '55527760'},
       '32548926': {'exam1': '9', 'project1': '7', 'classrecap': '77', 'homework': '98', 'exam2': '1', 'attendance': '43', 'project2': '86', 'id': '32548926'}}

print(generateReport(d))
```

Comment: with that I get multiple time  [attendance project2 classrecap project1 exam1 id exam2 homework (4 times  extra)]

Answer (score 0):

Really? The output I get is:

```
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Put your code into [repl.it](http://repl.it), it shows you the problem among the many warnings:

[image: screenshot of this code in repl.it editor, highlighting the problem]

The only places you write to the file are lines 14, and 17, which are in loops `for grades in students:` and `for val in students.values()`, but you haven't defined `students` anywhere.

You did use it as the loop variable in the previous loop, so the `students` has the ending value from the previous loop.

To fix it, you need to loop once over the gradebook to get one student at a time, and then for each entry you need to loop over the student's data to process the row for the file.

---

And what's with your title about 'in order'? It isn't clear whether you mean the columns, or the rows, or both, should be ordered, or what the order is. But it makes it rather silly that you're using an unordered data structure (a dictionary) when you could be using an ordered one (a tuple, a list) and that would make life easier.

(And what about the columns in your desired output which don't exist in your data, like Potential Grade? Or the way your desired headers are a different uppercase/spacing to your data, and Python is case sensitive so that's annoying? Or the way the `csv` module exists which can do a lot of this work for you).

1. You pass the data into `generateReport` with the name `gradebook` - use that name. When you use `d` you're reaching out of the function, into the parent scope, which is tangled and knotty, and it means `gradebook` never gets used, which is confusing and unhelpful to anyone reading it.
2. Use helpful names - `student_id` for iterating over the student IDs, rather than `stu`. `student` singular for a single thing, rather than `students`. Anything rather than `whatever`.
3. And close the outfile with `()` to call the close method.
4. And don't print the output of generateReport() ... because there is no return output from it to print.

Addressing all of that gets me to this: columns ordered and cased as your example output, input still as your example input, student rows sorted into order by ID.

```
def generateReport(gradebook):
    outfile=open('gradebook.txt','w')

    # all the columns, in the order they need to show up.
    columns = ('ID', 'Exam1', 'Exam2', 'Homework', 'Attendance',
           'Project1', 'Project2', 'Class Recap',
           'Final Grade', 'Potential Grade')

    # join the columns into a tab-separated line with a newline, and write it once
    header_line = '\t'.join(columns) + '\n'
    outfile.write(header_line)

    # sort the student IDs into (numeric) order:
    sorted_student_ids = sorted(gradebook.keys(), key=int)

    # loop over each student ID
    for student_id in sorted_student_ids:

      # for each student, get their data
      student_data = gradebook[student_id]

      # build up a line of output for this students, using the columns
      student_row = []
      for column in columns:

        # columns don't match the dictionary keys :|
        # remove spaces and make them lowercase, so they do
        # also handle where there is no data for a column and get '' instead
        # and convert to strings for writing to the file
        column = column.replace(' ', '').lower()
        value = str(student_data.get(column, ''))

        student_row.append(value)

      # now we have the data for this student, in the desired column order
      student_line = '\t'.join(student_row) + '\n'
      outfile.write(student_line)

    outfile.close()


d={'37340752': {'exam1': '50', 'project1': '40', 'classrecap': '39', 'homework': '62', 'exam2': '3', 'attendance': '17', 'project2': '86', 'id': '37340752'},
   '95255664': {'exam1': '76', 'project1': '60', 'classrecap': '39', 'homework': '81', 'exam2': '57', 'attendance': '19', 'project2': '42', 'id': '95255664'},
   '47718233': {'exam1': '81', 'project1': '55', 'classrecap': '53', 'homework': '46', 'exam2': '46', 'attendance': '4', 'project2': '14', 'id': '47718233'},
   '55527760': {'exam1': '34', 'project1': '89', 'classrecap': '39', 'homework': '19', 'exam2': '99', 'attendance': '78', 'pta': 65, 'project2': '99', 'id': '55527760'},
   '32548926': {'exam1': '9', 'project1': '7', 'classrecap': '77', 'homework': '98', 'exam2': '1', 'attendance': '43', 'project2': '86', 'id': '32548926'}}

generateReport(d)
with open('gradebook.txt') as f: 
  x = f.read() 
  print(x)
```

Which you can [run online at repl.it](https://repl.it/E5un/1), and there's a version using the CSV module afterwards, commented out.

- I have no affiliation with repl.it, I just like it a lot.